# Finding closest points equal in value in a grid

Tags: algorithms

Given a grid of integer values, $G = \{g_{i,j}\mid i<m,j<n\}$ I would like to compute a grid $H = \{\{x_{i,j},y_{i,j}\}\mid i<m,j<n\}$, in which each cell contains the coordinates of the cell in $G$ closest to ${i,j}$ and equal in value, i.e. find $x,y$ such that $g_{x_{i,j},y_{i,j}} = g_{i,j}$ and $(x-i)^2 + (y-j)^2$ is minimum.

My current approach is to use a tree of depth $p$, where each level $k$ of the tree divides the grid into $4^k$ tiles. For each node, I have a table that maps from value to sets of tiles one level below that contain that value. In leaves, I map from value to the actual cell. My procedure for finding $x_{i,j},y_{i,j}$ given $i,j$ is to descend the tree to find the leaf with the closest tile containing $h_{k,l}, h_{k,l} = g_{i,j}$, where $(k,l)\ne(i,j)$.

1. Is there a better general approach, such as a standard algorithm
2. Is there any theory around the idea of dividing a cartesian plane into a map in this manner that I can study to review techniques in this space?

Comment: The $m$ as depth for your tree and the $m$ used in the definition of $G, H$ are not the same right? Am I understanding correctly that your algorithm requires $O(nm\log(nm))$ to construct the tree and $O(\log(nm))$ for each query?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just edited to use a different variable $p$ for the depth. Yes, your assertions are correct.